stochastic process and integral
Let $(X_n(t))_{t\in [1,+\infty], n\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence of nonnegative random variables and $(\mathcal{F}_s)$ a filtration ($\mathcal{F}_s \subset \mathcal{F}_r$ for $s\leqslant r$). We assume that for each $n,t$, $X_n(t)$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\frac{n}{t}}$ measurable.
We set
$X_n := \int_{1}^{+\infty}X_n(t){\rm d}t $.
We assume that $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\mathbb{E}\big[X_{n+1}(t)\, \big|\,\, \mathcal{F}_{\frac{n}{t}}\,  \big] {\rm d}t \leqslant X_n $. Let $\lambda >0 $ and $N \geqslant 2$.
My question, could we have something like this :
$$
\lambda \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup_{1 \leqslant n\leqslant N} \{X_n >\lambda\} \right) \leqslant  \mathbb{E}[X_1] ?
$$
